# Verify that SET FOREIGN KEY CHECKS is set to = 1

Tags: mysql

I would like to DROP and create back the same table in using phpmyadmin.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_entity`;

CREATE TABLE `product_entity` ( ...... );
```

I get error message

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Then I set

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_entity`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
CREATE TABLE `product_entity` ( ...... );
```

My question is how to verify that SET FOREIGN KEY CHECKS is set to = 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this in console

```
SELECT @@foreign_key_checks;
```

### [**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29735)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. 6 mins more.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in console
`show variables like 'fo%'`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29738

Comment: foreign_key_checks : ON . execellent!